# Java/JSP : Making a executable Java working as webapp

Tags: java, jsp, web

I have a standard java project working local made by another person i know.
It's about data retrieving.
I need to develop a web app supposed to do the same thing but accessible by anyone via browser.
I CAN'T edit the code for that purpose, at least some implementation details. A kind of black box.

Can you suggest me the best approach to make a webapp based on a local executable app through JSP & servlet ecc?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not the site 'WriteMyCode'. Without more information especially code wise we cannot help you. You might check out the help page on how to write a question with a [Minimal, complete and verifiable exampte](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like [webswing](http://webswing.org/).

> What is Webswing ? Webswing is a web server that allows to run any swing application inside your web browser using only pure HTML5.
>
> The best days of swing framework are gone. Desktop applications lost
>   popularity and everything is forced to be online and mobile. But what
>   about existing application? Using applet technology proved to be
>   insecure, rewriting the application to web technology is too
>   expensive. This is where Webswing can help you. With Webswing, your
>   application is securely running on server and user's browser only
>   displays the application window. All this without changing single line
>   of source code.